# Active Record Select returning weird result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, filter

I am not sure why the "logo" url is being returned from the below query? I'm not looking for that to be returned. I am trying to return results that we can use to plot this on a map.

I do have a carrierwave uploader mounted on the Contractor model, so I'm assuming it's something there, but I have no idea why calling .to_json would cause the logo to show up?

This has been stumping me for a couple days. Not sure why this is happening

query:

```
contractors = Contractor.where.not(latitude: nil, longitude: nil).select([:id, :company_name, :latitude, :longitude])
```

active record response

```
#<Contractor id: 7441, company_name: "company name", latitude: 41.992063, longitude: -88.430357,>
```

when I add .to_json to it

```
{"id"=>7441, "company_name"=>"company name", "latitude"=>41.992063, "longitude"=>-88.700357, "logo"=>{"url"=>nil}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are only retrieving id, company_name, lat and long from the db, every other field from your model will be nil.

To avoid showing other fields when you use [`to_json`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json), you can do something like

```
contractors.to_json(only: [:id, :company_name, :latitude, :longitude])
```

Comment: awesome! That worked. Didn't know that was possible.Thank you.